# Can we specify DX runtime versions by project?

Tags: salesforcedx

With Spring '19 around the corner, I decided to set up a pre-release org and upgraded my client to 45.x. After playing around a bit, I then went back to work on my actual work projects, and came across an error:

> ERROR:  The configured apiVersion 45.0 is not supported for this org. The max apiVersion is 44.0.

Now, I'm not able to do any work in my sandbox! Is there a way I can use the correct API version in each project? For now, I have to switch between installing salesforcedx@latest and salesforcedx@pre-release each time I want to switch modes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After moving into a project folder, specify a version override with the following command:

```
sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=44.0
```

This will allow you to use the newer 45.0 features in a LWC project, whilst still being able to work in a 44.0 org without any errors.

Make sure that, if you're playing with an advanced version of the API, that you keep the `salesforcedx@pre-release` plugin installed until it is upgraded to the latest release.

Comment: Thanks, brilliant timing. I was just looking for this!

Comment: So, is it the case that a scratch org is 'locked' to the API version in which it was created? Or do they get updated when a release is pushed? I know it's not that big a deal since the half-life of a scratch is short... just curious.

Comment: @PatMcClellan__c It's not documented, but I presume so. I've heard they're working on a way to let us specify a version during pre-release windows, but I have no confirmation on this one way or the other.