# Deploy Authentication configuration settings with SFDX

Tags: customization, mydomain, theme-branding

In `MyDomain` settings, you can set branding for your login pages. You can set logo, colour, and etc. Can anyone advice me how to deploy these settings with `SFDX`. I have made these changed on a `ScratchOrg` and executed `sfdx force:source:pull -f` command. But it didn't fetch any changes related to above settings.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [MyDomainSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_mydomainsettings.htm). The [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/52) says that these settings are available for Source Tracking, so force:source:pull should have worked. Make sure your project is set to at least API version 47.0. Older versions of the API don't support this feature, which may be your problem. Check sfdx-project.json to make sure the API version is at least 47.0, and make sure you have not overridden [the current API version](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/243847/2984):

```
sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=
```

By not specifying a value, you'll use the latest version. Check both the "local" and "global" settings (using `--global` with `force:config:set`).

Comment: If looked at `MyDomainSettings` metadata. As you can see, there is no property related to logo or branding. It has only one `string` field which is `myDomainName`. Am I wrong?