# Is it possible to retrieve metadata for Authentication Configuration from MyDomain using sfdx or mdapi?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, metadata

The following settings are located at Setup -> My Domain (Authentication Configuration section) I'd like to be able to retrieve and deploy the settings (Specifically the "My Portal" Authentication Service) using sfdx or mdapi to higher environments. Is this possible? If so, where are these settings located?

I checked  the "[MyDomainSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_mydomainsettings.htm)" metadata and there is no key stating which Authentication Provider(s) I would like to use.

[image]

A similar question that addressed this problem is here but refers to Source tracking.

[Deploy Authentication configuration settings with SFDX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342504/deploy-authentication-configuration-settings-with-sfdx)